# How to use browser caching effectively for images?

Tags: http, browser, http-headers

Which combination of http headers can achieve the following?

I would like static content like images to be cached for as long as possible, but if those images change on the server, I would like the browsers to update them.

Comment: The same as always: a combination of the *maximum* cache duration desired and ensuring the server returns a content-not-modified. A smart server might also use [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) which would allow for more control beyond the last-modified-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very neat caching approach of static content is to encode version of your static content inside URL. Then "notifiying" browser to download new static content is just a matter of supplying new URLs to the client.

```
# first version access (1.1/main.css will never expire)
# e.g. by far future Cache-Control + Expires Header
<link ... href="/static/1.1/main.css

# after upgrading/releasing trigger fresh download
<link ... href="/static/1.2/main.css
```

It involves some effort to your build+deploy process but from caching control it is the very simple.

Comment: So if I have an expires or cahce-control header with say a yeat expiry, there is no way to tell the browser to check if an item has been updated?

Comment: Basically 2 cache-style: 1) Conditional-GET (browser is doing expclitly a call to check new content, e.g. by ETag or If-Modified-Since, resulting in 304 Not-Modified or 200 OK updated content) . 2) Telling browser to not do a call at all (e.g. Cache-Control: max-age, Expires header). 2) has the advantage that you don't cause traffic at all, but has the disadvantage that update-forcing won't be possible. So I would use style 2) only if I am sure that content (identified by URL) won't ever get updated (see my initial answer).

Comment: so there is no combination of headers that will cache files for a long time, but still do a check for updated content. It's either one or the other?

Comment: yes there is only either/or. You could combine both Conditional-GET (e.g. ETag) and Cache-Control: max-age, but the core problem is how to find out the "right" max-age value. It is hard to know content is updated (like unplanned bug-fix rollout). Therefore in my view the caching approach with changing URL for new content is optimal (reduced server calls + having the referred static content under server's control).